# Emacs -- How to create a vertical strike-through effect

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some suggestions, please, of how to create the visual effect of a vertical `strike-through` (with the character *on top* of the vertical bar ("\u007C") still being visible).  If layering is possible, then the vertical bar should be underneath so that the letter is mostly visible.

I searched for a method of superimposing characters, layering overlays, and I looked at some xpm images, however, I have not found anything remotely close to what I'm looking for.  The goal is to have a true cross-hairs effect similar to the image below -- the gray background would be replaced with a yellow vertical strike-through so that the letters would still be visible.

[image: Example]

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you seen [column-marker](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker)?  I use it to highlight characters passed a predefined limit, and wondering if it could be leveraged for your purpose.  It's a neat idea though, what would you use the cross-hairs for (if you don't mind sharing)?

Comment: Also might want to look at [crosshair highlighting](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/CrosshairHighlighting) if you haven't yet.

Comment: @nymo and @Carl Groner -- The highlighting methods utilized by the publicly available vertical line libraries use font-lock or overlays or .xpm images.  However, I've never seen an example where a *vertical* line can actually strike-through another character.  Although it is possible to create a horizontal `strike-through` with `:strike-through t`, there is no vertical `strike-through`.  Essentially, I'm looking for a way to *merge* two overlays -- or, create a semi-transparent overlay that lets something underneath be seen.  In a nutshell, I want to have a pipe ("\u007C") underneath a letter.

Comment: nymo and @Carl Groner -- I've added a second image to illustrate the visual effect I'm looking for.

Comment: @nymo -- One of my favorite features of Sublime Text 2 and 3 is the CursorRuler written by Ron Martinez.  I've combined features from the various vertical line libraries publicly available for Emacs, and I created something that is compatible with `visual-line-mode` and `whitespace-mode`.  For spaces and anything without a character, I'm using the vertical bar -- Unicode 007C.  The vertical line is great for visually aligning stuff, and it helps me see exactly where I am on the screen without having to hunt for the cursor.

Comment: @lawlist, why don't you implement something like `:strike-through-vertical` in the C parts of Emacs? Admittedly, you would have to wait until the next public Emacs release to have it wide-spread, but you would get there eventually.

Comment: @Lindydancer -- thank you for the suggestion.  Yes, adding a feature to the C parts of Emacs would indeed be a worthy venture someday.  However, such a venture would require a *substantial* learning swerve on my part.  I put together a working draft this evening of concatenating a zero-width-space `\uFEFF` (with color) and the letter/character at `point` with a slightly reduced `:size` so that the two occupy the same space as a regular size character.  The effect is a vertical bar to the immediate left of the character and a reduced size character to the right.  A few more kinks to work out."

Comment: You say "*The highlighting methods utilized by the publicly available vertical line libraries use font-lock or overlays or .xpm images*" Not so. [`vline.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/vline.el) (used by [`crosshairs.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/crosshairs.el)) can use character composition (see option `vline-style`), and it *does* have the effect of a vertical strike-through on characters.

Comment: @Drew -- Thank you for the clarification of the `compose-chars` usage.  I just wish it could work on OSX, but sadly that won't work on Snow Leopard and the Emacs development team closed the bug without fixing it:  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20537

Comment: @lawlist: From reading that bug thread, my impression is that they think they fixed it. Consider reopening it (or asking that it be reopened), showing a specific recipe that shows it not working. Apart from that, the post here should perhaps say that it doesn't work on that particular platform (and cite the bug), rather than giving the impression that it doesn't work in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feature Request #17684 (crosshairs) [ https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17684 ] and Feature Request 22873 (multiple fake cursors) [ https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22873 ] are a work in progress.  Although it is unknown whether these features will ever be incorporated into the official Emacs, there is a working draft proof concept that has been posted to both of the above-mentioned feature requests.  The features require modifications to both the C and Lisp internals prior to building a GUI version of Emacs from the master branch -- X11, Windows or NS.

---

**EXAMPLE 1 of 3**:

The following code snippet works with *some* fonts on *some* operating systmes -- e.g., it works out of the box on Windows; however, it does *not* work for this author on OSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard or Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8.  [See bug report number 20537 -- https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20537 -- even though the bug report has been officially closed by the Emacs development team, this author has never been able to get that feature working on Snow Leopard subsequent to the "bug fix". :( ]  The user may wish to experiment with the glyph reference points, and the variable `reference-point-alist` in `composite.el` has a detailed doc-string in relation thereto.  The user may also wish to experiment with using an `after-string` or `before-string` display property.  The library `vline.el` at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vline.el has a variable named `vline-style`, which can be set to `'face`, `'compose`, or `'mixed` -- the latter two settings cause `vline` to use a slight variation of this code snippet [see lines 362 to 370 of said library].

```lisp
(let* (
    (point-min (point-min))
    (point-max (point-max))
    (pt (point))
    (pt+1 (1+ pt))
    (char (char-after pt))
    (line-char (string-to-char "|"))
    (str (when char (compose-chars char '(tc . tc) line-char))) ) 
  (overlay-put (make-overlay pt pt+1) 'display str)
  (sit-for 2)
  (remove-overlays point-min point-max 'display str))
```

---

**EXAMPLE 2 of 3**:

The following code snippet uses a unicode character known as a zero-with space (i.e., `uFEFF`).  Because a space cannot receive a foreground color, a background color is used to give the zero-width space the apparance of a thin vertical line that stretches the entire line height.  As used in the context of this code snippet, the zero-width space has a width of 1 pixel and the concatenated charcter is reduced in size so that the two combined characters have a width equal to the `frame-char-width`.  Testing of this snippet was done on an OSX operating system using the default font of `-*-Monaco-normal-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`.  The cursor is removed for a short duration during this example so that the overlay can be seen more clearly.

```lisp
(let* (
    (point-min (point-min))
    (point-max (point-max))
    (pt (point))
    (pt+1 (1+ pt))
    (char (char-after pt))
    (char-str (when char (char-to-string char)))
    (ln-char-str (char-to-string ?\uFEFF))
    (str (when char
      (concat
        (propertize ln-char-str 'face '(:background "red"))
        (propertize char-str 'face '(:height 100))))) )
  (internal-show-cursor nil nil)
  (overlay-put (make-overlay pt pt+1) 'display str)
  (sit-for 2)
  (internal-show-cursor nil t)
  (remove-overlays point-min point-max 'display str))
```

---

**EXAMPLE 3 of 3**:

The following is an example using an overlay with an xpm image for graphical Emacs versions that support xpm image format.  It is 11 pixels wide; 20 pixels high; and has 4 preselected colors.  I am on a Mac running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and the font I prefer when using Emacs is `-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1` -- the `frame-char-width` is 11 and the `frame-char-height` is 20.  I have added a thin vertical yellow line to the left of the capital letter "A" as an example of how to draw custom images.  Substitution of the character at point can be made programmatically using `(char-after (point))` and taking that number -- which in this case is 65 for the capital letter "A" -- and substituting the appropriate variable -- e.g., `(cond ((eq (char-after (point)) 65) cap-ltr-a-xpm) . . .` -- and using that variable in the the overlay placement -- e.g., `(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (1+ (point))) 'display cap-ltr-a-xpm)`.  This works very nicely for both truncated buffers and also with word-wrap because the `display` overlay property on a character in the middle of a word does not cause word-wrap to think that the first part of the word belongs at the end of the previous line.  Naturally, it will take time to create a custom library of favorite xpm images.  The cursor is removed for a short duration during this example so that the overlay can be seen more clearly.

ImageMagick is capable of producing a semi-accurate xpm of a particular character based on a specific font family and size, but it was not as precise as I had hoped -- here is a link to instructions for using that external utility:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168154/2112489  In a nutshell, the user should be prepared to spend time customizing the xpm images to his / her liking.

```lisp
(let* (
    (pt (point))
    (pt+1 (1+ pt))
    (point-min (point-min))
    (point-max (point-max))
    (cap-ltr-a-xpm `(image :type xpm :mask nil :ascent center :data
      "/* XPM */
      static char * letters_xpm[] = {
      /* columns rows colors chars-per-pixel */
      /* columns = 1 pixel in width -- see also (frame-char-width) */
      /* rows = 1 pixel in height -- see also (frame-char-height) */
      \"11 20 4 1\",
      \". c #000000\",
      \"+ c #FF0000\",
      \"@ c #7F0000\",
      \"% c yellow\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%....++....\",
      \"%....++....\",
      \"%..++..++..\",
      \"%..++..++..\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++++++++++\",
      \"%++++++++++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%++......++\",
      \"%..........\"};"))  )
  (internal-show-cursor nil nil)
  (overlay-put (make-overlay pt pt+1) 'display cap-ltr-a-xpm)
  (sit-for 2)
  (internal-show-cursor nil t)
  (remove-overlays point-min point-max 'display cap-ltr-a-xpm))
```

The following code snippet is similar to the one above, except it uses the `after-string` display property.  The cursor is removed for a short duration during this function so that the overlay can be seen more clearly.

```lisp
(let* (
    (point-min (point-min))
    (point-max (point-max))
    (peol (point-at-eol))
    (pilcrow `(image :type xpm :mask nil :ascent center :data
      "/* XPM */
      static char * pilcrow_xpm[] = {
      \"11 20 4 1\",
      \". c #000000\",
      \"+ c orange\",
      \"@ c #7F0000\",
      \"% c yellow\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..++++++..\",
      \"%.++++.+...\",
      \"%.++++.+...\",
      \"%.++++.+...\",
      \"%..+++.+...\",
      \"%....+.+...\",
      \"%....+.+...\",
      \"%....+.+...\",
      \"%....+.+...\",
      \"%....+.+...\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\",
      \"%..........\"};"))
    (pilcrow-str (propertize " " 'display pilcrow)) )
  (overlay-put (make-overlay peol peol) 'after-string pilcrow-str)
  (sit-for 2)
  (remove-overlays point-min point-max 'after-string pilcrow-str))
```

---

The following screenshot was made using the second example.

[image: Example]