# How to use `setcdr` with buffer-local variables

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am experiencing behavior using `setcdr` that would seem to suggest that it is not confined to buffer-local variables containing the same name in different buffers.  I have tried using `with-current-buffer`, but that does not correct the issue.

For example, `buffer-A` and `buffer-B` both contain a local-variable named `variable-one`, which is a `cons` cell -- e.g., `(overlay-string t)`, and `setcdr` is being used to set the `cdr` value to either `t` or `nil`.

Is there a way to ensure that `setcdr` remains confined to modifying only the buffer-local value?

Comment: Thank you both, @phils and @ale -- The usage of the lessons that I am learning in this thread will require *at least* one cup of coffee, because I am using a `dolist` macro and the lists / variables are several `(car (car (cdr (car (cdr . . .` deep.  I'll pick this up again tomorrow morning.  Your answers are greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there *is* no buffer-local value for the cdr of the list.

If two variables point at the same list, and you modify the list, then you will see the effect in both the variables.

That has nothing to do with buffer-local variables, and everything to do with what it means to assign a list to a variable.

If you want the two variables to point to *different* lists, then you need to copy the entire list.

You can use `(copy-sequence LIST)` to copy a list. Or `(append LIST nil)` is also common (as append copies all except the final argument).

n.b. Those functions create a new list *structure*, but the *values* in the list are still the original objects. Typically that's all that's required, but if you do need the list contents to be entirely independent of one another, then use `copy-tree` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, as with `setcdr` you are modifying the value bound to the variable you declared buffer-local. If you didn't assign a new value to the buffer-local variable, that value is its default value. Note that what is *buffer local* is the binding of the variable name to its value.

The only way (that I know) would be to assign a copy to your buffer-local variable and then use `setcdr`.
This needs to be done in *every* buffer.

An alternative is to not use `setcdr` at all, and use `setq` instead:

`(setcdr foo bar) ===> (setq foo (cons (car foo) bar))`

Comment: Your answer is correct and so is the one above, but I could only choose one.  I ended up using a combination of your suggestion, with the `copy-sequence` suggestion above.  Your help is greatly appreciated!