# Incorporate variable name into `dolist` cycle and change its value

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to incorporate the name of a **buffer-local** variable into the `dolist` cycle, and change the value of that **buffer-local** variable.  `setq` and `setq-local` reject all of the variable name variations that I have tried.  In the `dolist` cycle, the variable name is `(car (car (cdr test)))`.

The same variable name will be used in more than one buffer, with each buffer having a different value.

This project is related two (2) other recent threads of mine, but I believe this is a somewhat unique issue.  The related threads are as follows:   [How to use `setcdr` with buffer-local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500504/how-to-use-setcdr-with-buffer-local-variables) **and** [How to use a cons cell to define and later remove overlays with `dolist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467815/how-to-use-a-cons-cell-to-define-and-later-remove-overlays-with-dolist)

I have tried all of the following, and a few other variations, without success:

```
(setq (car (car (cdr test))) newlist)

(setq var newlist)

(setq (make-symbol (car (car (cdr test)))) newlist)

(setq (intern (car (car (cdr test)))) newlist)
```

I have also tried modifying the list to use a string, e.g., `'("variable-one" ,variable-one)`

---

**Here is the test code**:

```lisp
(defvar variable-one '(a t))

(make-variable-buffer-local 'variable-one)

(defvar variable-two '(c t))

(make-variable-buffer-local 'variable-two)

(defvar variable-three '(e t))

(make-variable-buffer-local 'variable-three)

(dolist (test `(
    '(variable-one ,variable-one)
    '(variable-two ,variable-two)
    '(variable-three ,variable-three) ))
  (let* (
      (var (car (car (cdr test))))
      (newlist (copy-list (car (cdr (car (cdr test)))))) )
    (setcdr newlist nil)
    (message "var: %s | newlist: %s" var newlist)
    ;; (setq (car (car (cdr test))) newlist)
  ))
```

---

**EDIT** (August 26, 2014):  The following revision is based upon the helpful suggestions provided by everyone in this thread -- greatly appreciated!  :)  I still need to conduct some buffer-local tests with multiple buffers later on today, but the suggestions made by the forum participants seem to work with the test outline below.

```lisp
(defvar variable-one '(a t))

(make-variable-buffer-local 'variable-one)

(defvar variable-two '(c t))

(make-variable-buffer-local 'variable-two)

(defvar variable-three '(e t))

(make-variable-buffer-local 'variable-three)

(dolist (test `(
    (variable-one ,variable-one)
    (variable-two ,variable-two)
    (variable-three ,variable-three) ))
  (let* (
      (var (car test))
      (newlist (copy-list (car (cdr test)))) )
    (setcdr newlist nil)
    (message "var: %s | newlist: %s" var newlist)
    (set (car test) newlist) ))
```

Comment: Couple of quick points.  First, `(car (car (cdr test)))` can be expressed more compactly as `(caadr test)`.  Second, you can use the `setf` macro to set places like `(setf (caadr test) newlist)`.

Comment: @Dan -- thank you for the shortcut using `caadr`.  I'll need to read up on the difference between `set` (as suggested by Tom Tromey below) and `setf` -- both seem to work well in the context of the example in this thread.

Comment: `setf` is the general setter for Common Lisp, and it works in elisp as well (actually, use of `setq` is relatively rare in CL, as it has largely been superceded by `setf`).  Here's a useful thread on [the differences between `set`, `setq`, and `setf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869529/difference-between-set-setq-and-setf-in-common-lisp).

Comment: Should be no need for the quote marks before "(variable...".  The backquote suffices.

Comment: @Drew -- without the single quote before `(variable...`, I get `. . . (wrong-type-argument listp t)`

Comment: That's because the arg to `copy-list` is `(cadr (cadr test))` and `test` is `(variable-one (a t))`. It has nothing to do with what I mentioned. Your variables have the wrong values, or you are using the wrong `car` and `cdr` combinations, depending on what you want. You can test this kind of thing yourself. Just add binding `(IGNORE (debug))` after the first binding, for example.

Comment: @Drew: actually the innermost `cdr` and `car` in the `let*` binding values are for getting past the redundant `quote`; you have to change both at once to stay consistent.

Comment: @npostavs: Sure, no doubt. My point was not that simply removing the quote marks would make his code do something useful. The point is that there is no need to quote anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by the "dolist cycle".

The root of your problem is that `setq` is a special form.  The first argument doesn't need to be quoted -- that is what the "q" means.

You want to use `set` instead.

Comment: Thank you -- that looks like it did the trick.  I'll do some more testing this morning with multiple buffers and report back later today.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a general rule, if you need `set` (and/or `symbol-value`, `eval`, and a few of their relatives) you're probably doing something wrong.