# Emacs - Create vertical line

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I want to highlight the current column where the cursor is, but there is no default mode in emacs for that. Then, I tried to install vline package, but the highlight color seems confused with the text. I am not sure how to change the color in vline package as well. Is there anyone try to create vertical line in emacs before?

Comment: I've invested a zillion hours on this exact issue.  Certain fonts with vline-mode permit a vertical strike-through by setting that option; whereas, other fonts do not support the vertical strike-through.  vline-mode also comes with highlights instead of a vertical strike-through.  I have my own minor-mode that has been a work in progress for many months, but it so highly customized, it is not really useful for people with different fonts and/or non-English characters.  Here is a link to an early draft, which I've come quite a long way since:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23813217/2112489

Comment: Here is a link to an answer by Drew regarding packages that offer this feature:  http://superuser.com/a/691711/206164  I prefer my own, but like I said, I've invested a zillion hours . . . so as to support `visual-line-mode`, etc.  In terms of your colors and so forth, you're going to need to open up the vline source code and digest it -- be prepared to spend time on this issue.  If you are just adjusting vline-mode, you are not going to need a zillion hours . . . but perhaps a few hours . . .  :)  If you post more details and/or a screen shot, I or someone may be able to help.

Comment: Haha, that's a good experience! Thanks @lawlist.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your question that is not a duplicate of, say, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744237/729907) asks how to change the color of the vline face.

The answer is simple: look at some of the faces and user options defined by `vline.el`:

Faces:

- `vline`: "A default face for vertical line highlighting."
- `vline-visual`: "A default face for vertical line highlighting in visual lines."

Options:

- `vline-face`: "A face for vertical line highlighting." (default: face `vline`)
- `vline-visual-face`: "A face for vertical line highlighting in visual lines." (default: `vline-visual`)

IOW customize one or more of these, to change the appearance of the vertical line. (And of course, option `vline-style` needs to have value `face` or `mixed` if you want to use a face.)

Comment: Thanks @Drew, for pointing it out! I will take a look and try it out.

Comment: I tried to change the background color of vline, and vline-visual but nothing happens.

Comment: Check that `vline-style` says that you are using a face.

Comment: Yes, it's using face. Anyway, I am using col-highlight.el now. After changing the background color, it seems working fine for me. Thanks a lot for your help.