# Is there a way to style or otherwise control color or other visual characteristics of a part of a particular Org mode file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to style or otherwise control color or other visual characteristics of a part of a particular Org mode file (say, through properties or even some other Emacs lisp code)? Like say, a particular topic and all its subtopics would have a colored border or background grouping them or ?

The purpose for me is to provide a more appealing and visually obvious differentiation between topics at the same level in a file with lots of topics at the same level (which each, in turn, may have many subtopics). Think of it kind of like the concept of topic grouping in mind mapping software.

Update 1:

I searched a bit on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744237/emacs-how-to-create-a-vertical-strike-through-effect) and [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/ways-to-unobtrusively-vary-text-rendering) links that maybe show a general approach using overlays (the links are of course to a totally different topic, but may hold keys to how to do such a thing -- I know nothing yet about programming overlays or similar visual properties in Emacs). Also it seems like [mwe-color-box.el](http://foldr.org/~michaelw/emacs/) (links shows a screenshot) might be helpful in this regard. [ov.el](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/ov.el) also looks very useful.

Update 2:

One hacky solution I came up with is to put a topic headline that is visual only, like a bunch of hyphens with maybe a string of text in the middle that serves as a group name. Then another such headline with the text below (at the bottom of) the topics I wish to group. Then put pipes, |, at the beginning and end of each topic headline in the group (to simulate the left and right hand side borders of a "group" box). Then I can use the following elisp (using ov.el) above:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp    :results silent :exports none
 (let ((properties '(:foreground "yellow"
                                 :background "cyan"
                                 ;; :height 1.5
                                 )))
   (ov-clear 'ov1)
   (ov-set "+-+<<.*>>-+\\+" 'face properties 'ov1 t)
   (ov-set "+-+\\+" 'face properties 'ov1 t)
   (ov-set
    (ov-regexp "| +\\(Analysis\\|Algebra\\|Statistics\\|Probability\\) +|")
    'face properties 'ov1 t))
(ov-set ".*" 'face '(:overline nil) 'ov2 t) ; for this buffer, I don't want
                                            ; leuven's underlining of headlines
 (let ((properties '(:foreground "brown"
                                 :background "yellow"
                                 :box t)))
   (ov-clear 'ov3)
   (ov-set
    (ov-regexp "Quicklinks.*$")
    'face properties 'ov3 t))
#+end_src
```

Combining that with the leuven color theme (which is especially nice with org mode) results in a pretty nice looking color group. If you look at the text area where you'd insert a group name (above), note that the << and >> can then be referenced by an Org mode link. I use such things, say, to provide like a 'quick links' section at the top of a larger Org mode file full of research wherein there is some particular content I want to just jump to. I then create a yasnippet that generates such empty groups with a field to fill in for the <<.*>> section and then cut and paste (or create) topics between the group delimiters.

Screenshot 
[image]

Better of course would be a proper bit of elisp, maybe something like org-indent.el that would read custom org properties or something to do overlays automatically. You could also maybe walk the org tree using the tree walker from org-mindmap.el and instead of doing what it does to generate dot it could instead generate overlays in the current buffer based on properties (if present). You'd presumably hook that up to a key binding and then be able to toggle such overlays. Just thinking out loud...

Comment: One possibility would be to gather the data and create your own custom `*Org Agenda*` type buffer with your own rules -- e.g., overlays, or font-lock, or text-properties.  That might be easier than trying to alter the appearance of a classic `org-mode` buffer.  Basically, you would need your own regexp to gather the data and put it into a list -- then regurgitate the list into a new buffer -- adding formatting as you go and/or text-properties -- overlays and/or font-lock would be applied after the regurgitation process.

Comment: If you want a something to go through all the headlines one by one, use `org-map-entries` from `org.el`.

Comment: what about just highlight-regexp? I use something like:
(highlight-regexp "Optimal" 'mu4e-modeline-face)

Comment: @suvayu, thanks for the org-map-entries, very helpful.

Comment: @JohnKitchin, thanks I didn't know about hightlight-regexp, much appreciated.