# How to have multiple fill column indicator emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I want to have line ruler at 80 chars and 72 chars in emacs. I am using emacs 24. I know there is fill-column-indicator but it has provision only for one line ruler.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that you modify a library for column highlight, or modify the one you are already using to support multiple guidelines: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3395/2287  You can also modify one of the these column indicator packages:  http://superuser.com/a/691711/206164  See also this related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23813217/2112489  The main usage of resources each command loop is forward-line or vertical-motion or re-search-backward/forward for new lines.