# Extended Crosshair Cursor for Emacs

Tags: emacs, highlight, text-cursor

I've recently switched from working in the ISPF text editor over to emacs. The only feature that I really miss was the extended crosshair cursor in ISPF, which I have shown below. IS there anything like this available in emacs? Closest I've found is **setq cursor-type 'bar** or **'hbar**, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

If there is any way to modify these, maybe by combining them and extending the lines, I think that could work but don't know where to start and haven't seen anything on this.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I've been working on implementing this and I've come pretty darn close with the upcoming version 010 patch of a proof concept for multiple fake cursors implemented in C relating to feature request #22873; however, the Emacs development team is still thinking over that feature request -- and they've been thinking about it for more than a year now.  Apparently, I'm the only one motivated -- but, I'm not a real programmer.  For a few years, I was using custom XPM images.  See this related thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744237/emacs-how-to-create-a-vertical-strike-through-effect

Comment: Note that none of the publicly available libraries are able to handle the situation when the variable `word-wrap` is set to `t` and the variable `truncate-lines` is set to `nil`, and when the line spans several visible screen lines.  I have enabled that in a custom version, but it is limited to just the visible window and requires yet another custom modification to C to properly calculate window-start and window-end in all circumstances such as scrolling.  Even with all my hacks, it is still too slow to draw every keystroke due to `vertical-motion` time cost -- so I have it on an idle-timer.

Comment: Thanks lawlist. I read through that thread and it is reassuring that there are others pushing for the same feature. I'll admit that I'm new to emacs so much of it is over my head, though I'm slowly learning to understand it and it seems this feature is more complicated than I had originally imagined. I wish I had more to offer the effort but keep fighting the good fight! I'll stay updated on that feature req.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Crosshairs Highlighting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting), library [**`crosshairs.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/crosshairs.el).

It provides these commands:

- **`toggle-crosshairs-when-idle`** – Highlight the current line and column whenever Emacs is idle more than a certain number of seconds.
- **`crosshairs-mode`** – Continually highlight the current line and column, tracking the cursor as it moves. If you bind this to a key, you can also use it to briefly show the current line and column, by hitting the key twice.
- **`flash-crosshairs`** – Highlight the current line and column for a few seconds. Another way to show the current line and column temporarily. You can show each for different lengths of time: line and column.

Library `crosshairs.el` requires libraries [`hl-line+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-line%2b.el), [`col-highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/col-highlight.el), and [`vline.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/vline.el).

Comment: Looks like this is the closest I can get with what is currently available to me. Certainly better than what I've been using. Thanks Drew!